# Does react-native optimize JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, optimization, uglifyjs

I read a guide on compilers. They have many optimization techniques like removing redundant code or removing unused variables and none used methods.
But script languages like javascript don't have compiler, so take it will not have optimizations.
I read a article about js optimizer like:

```
- Google Closure Compiler https://github.com/google/closure-compiler
- UglifyJS https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS
```

And the real question is Does platforms like react-native, angular, use code optimizer or should I use it myself?

Comment: JS typically runs on a JIT compiler and those certainly make optimizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The React Native script bundler, [Metro](https://github.com/facebook/metro), first transpiles your code using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). In production build mode, it then runs your code through [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).

The default configuration doesn't do any advanced optimizations such as tree-shaking or deduping.

If you want to apply more advanced optimizations, you can try to see if they can be achieved during the transpilation step using Babel plugins. If not, it may be easiest to use [Haul](https://github.com/callstack/haul), a webpack-based alternative bundler for React Native.

However, as always, before optimizing prematurely, think about what metrics you are trying to improve and measure whether your optimizations actually achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has released [Hermes](https://github.com/facebook/hermes) last year.
Hermes is an open-source JavaScript engine optimized for running React Native apps on Android. For many apps, enabling Hermes will result in improved start-up time, decreased memory usage, and smaller app size. At this time Hermes is an opt-in React Native feature, and this guide explains how to enable it.

Actually, my app has been smaller from 33M to 21M, utilizing this engine.